# Java code cannot run in jersey web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have a scala script (the script is about calculating metrix), it is wrapped in a shell script. I want to run the shell script in java.

It can be run sucessfully in Java console (run sucessful in Java project).
But when I new a web project, I put the same code in a new java class, it cannot be run.

I need to use that output in rest web service, how can I get the results successfully?

```
public class Return {
  public static void main(String[] args) {                  
      String s = null;
      try {
          String[] command = { "/Users/glange/hello.sh"};
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
          BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(s);
          }
          System.exit(0);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }                                                                     
}
```

I have tested the code which runs simple command line, such as ping google.com(Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.com"); it runs well, so it is not the problem of the code.
That means I cannot call that scala script(which wrapped in the shell script) in web project?

The shell script is here, actully it is spark job written in scala. It works well in java project but cannot work in web project, I am stuck, please help me.

```
/Users/glange/spark/bin/spark-submit --class predictlabel target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar buildings.model Building31925.0.json
```

Comment: Do you get exception? Does your script path/directory is correct?

Comment: no exception, click run and get nothing. The path/directory is correct coz it can be run successfully in java project